# postgresql: live tuples not matching table row count

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

We're experiencing poor performance with a table. The table is regularly updated with insert/updates, and is a critical table in an application.

In looking into the problem I've noticed that the row count of the table returned by

```
select count(1) from tablename;
```

returns ~8 million rows, this is expected and matches the source.

However looking at pg_class and pg_stat_user_tables shows a live tuple count of ~30 million (and a dead tuple count of ~26 million).

Shouldn't live tuples match the table row count? Could this discrepancy be causing my performance issues when querying the table?

Comment: The actual number of rows (obtained by counting them) will be more or less similar to `pg_stat_user_tables`' `n_live_tup` only if the table was recently (auto)analyzed.

What are your autovacuum settings?  And could you please show the output of `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE relname = 'yourtable';`?

Comment: Does an ANALYZE of the table fix the problem?  If not, does a VACUUM of it?  What's is your version (including the minor (bug-fix) release number)?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Did you get anywhere with this?